# 11.04 to 11.10 upgrade aborted due to power cut, now Update Manager saying No internet Connection

Tags: 11.04, partial-upgrade

While ***upgrading to 11.10 from 11.04***, because of powercut, the system got switched off abruptly(due to no back-up battery) and the upgrade got aborted in the midway.

Next time when I connected to internet, I found that I'm still in 11.04 and I'm unable to find upgrade to 11.10 and also now when I try to check for updates, I'm getting a pop-up saying "**No Internet Connection**". But I'm connected to internet and surfing as usual. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you repair your installation from a live CD or USB. Here's how:

1. Boot the live CD/USB.
2. Make sure you have an Internet connection in the live environment.
3. Set up a `chroot` environment. This means that you'll be in your system and able to make changes, but running within a working environment.

   - Open up a terminal window.
   - Mount your main partition. If you don't know its name, you can use GParted to find it. I'm assuming here that it's `dev/sda1`, but *make sure you use the correct one!*

     ```
     sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
     ```
   - Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

     ```
     for i in /sys /proc /dev /run; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
     ```
   - Everything's set up. Now `chroot` in. When completed, you'll be in your install as root.

     ```
     sudo chroot /mnt
     ```
4. Try to repair your install. If the first command fails, follow any instructions you're given. Failing that, try the second command.

   ```
   apt-get install
   aptitude install
   ```
5. If you still have problems, please edit your questions with the results of your efforts.
6. If things finished without errors, you should be good to go.

   ```
   exit  # leave the chroot environment
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I try this with regular version or alternate version of ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: @Rahul: You need to use a live CD or a live DVD. Last I knew, the alternate version wasn't a live CD. But if it is now, you can use it. I know for sure that the regular version works.