# Ubuntu 9.04 upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10 failed, initramfs? SOS

Tags: 11.10, installation, 9.04, initramfs

I was trying to upgrade my company desktop Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 11.10.

However, run until half way, the electric line was breakdown.

When I reboot the computer again, the installation is incomplete and all the files seem gone!

When I click install Ubuntu, there is no detected operating system!

Gosh! how should I do?

All my company P&C files haven't backed-up yet.

Comment: You cannot skip versions when you upgrade (only LTS can upgrade to the next LTS), so you should have done the path 9.04 -> 9.10 -> 10.04 -> 10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10: in my opinion, in this case it is far better to do a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

First, try booting with a live CD. You might be able to mount the filesystem on your harddisk and save your files that way. (Always make backups of important data!).

After you've rescued your files, do a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10. (Note, this will delete all files on your harddisk, so make sure you've rescued any important data before you do this).

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, the upgrade you're trying to do is unsupported and is likely to be fraught with problems. However, for this particular problem, there *is* a solution that has at least a 70% chance of working. I posted it in an [answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/88874/13398).